# How to i can fix issue in magento 2.1.2 (There has been an error processing your request)?

Tags: magento2, database

When i install magento 2.1.2, after complete installation when i open front view of website then i'm getting this error again and again... i install my magento again and again but same issue is occurred.

> Error: There has been an error processing your request Exception
>   printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 238886554

Please help me how to i can fix this issue.

```
 (Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO customer_visitor (customer_id, session_id, last_visit_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:13034:"#0
```

**Solution: TRUNCATE customer_visitor table from database.**

Comment: check your var/report folder for file 238886554. Check the error in that file

Comment: There this error is showing (Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `customer_visitor` (`customer_id`, `session_id`, `last_visit_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:13034:"#0

Comment: it's better if you update the question and add the full error message. don't write it in the comments.

Comment: Execute TRUNCATE customer_visitor;  in your Magento2 database

Comment: @Abdul Thanks, issue resolved. Thanks a lot... can you please tell why this error is coming ?

Comment: @WajahatBashir  I think insert blank entry in your database table => customer_visitor